# ROS 1 bridge requires the topic to be published both sides

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the ROS 1 / 2 communication steps [from this ROS-I tuto](https://industrial-training-master.readthedocs.io/en/melodic/_source/session7/ROS1-ROS2-bridge.html) trying to run a simple example : publish some `Bool` msg in ROS 1 and echo in ROS 2, and vice versa. As advised in the tuto, I have 3 workspaces: `ros_ws` for Noetic, `ros2_ws` for Foxy, `ros1_bridge_ws` for the bridge (foxy branch, compiled successfully with colcon). I'm running all terminals in localhost with default settings and DDS implementation.

**Terminal 1: Bridge in `ros1_bridge_ws` workspace**

```
source ros1_bridge_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 run ros1_bridge dynamic_bridge
```

**Terminal 2: roscore in `ros_ws` workspace**
source ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
roscore

The bridge in terminal 1 then warns:

```
[ERROR] [1595868742.350252486]: Tried to advertise on topic [/rosout] with latch=0 but the topic is already advertised with latch=1
created 2to1 bridge for topic '/rosout' with ROS 2 type 'rcl_interfaces/msg/Log' and ROS 1 type 'rosgraph_msgs/Log'
```

**Terminal 3: rostopic pub in `ros_ws` workspace**

ROS 1 will publish `False` booleans every second:

```
source ros_ws/devel/setup.bash
rostopic pub /test std_msgs/Bool "data: false" -r1
```

The bridge does not display anything new.

**Terminal 4: rostopic echo in `ros2_ws` workspace**

```
ros2 topic echo /test
WARNING: topic [/test] does not appear to be published yet
Could not determine the type for the passed topic
```

Thus ROS 2 does not get any message from ROS 1. I keep the publisher and subscriber open.

**Terminal 5: ros2 topic pub in `ros2_ws` workspace**

ROS 2 will publish `True` booleans every second:

```
source ros2_ws/install/setup.bash
ros2 topic pub /test std_msgs/Bool "data: true"
```

The bridge does not display anything new.

**Terminal 4: rostopic echo in `ros2_ws` workspace**

Back to the temrinal 4 that was falling to retrieve `False` messages from ROS1 and retry the echo:

```
ros2 topic echo /test
```

Now the echo receives successfully both `True` and `False` messages from ROS 1 and ROS 2 but also the bridge has noticed a new conversion to be made:

```
created 1to2 bridge for topic '/test' with ROS 1 type 'std_msgs/Bool' and ROS 2 type 'std_msgs/msg/Bool'
[INFO] [1595869460.462758826] [ros_bridge]: Passing message from ROS 1 std_msgs/Bool to ROS 2 std_msgs/msg/Bool (showing msg only once per type)
[WARN] [1595869460.463629720] [ros_bridge]: Message from ROS 2 rcl_interfaces/msg/Log failed to be passed to ROS 1 rosgraph_msgs/Log because the ROS 1 publisher is invalid (showing msg only once per type)
```

**Conclusion**

Why do I need to publish both sides to get some messages?
Note: this issue is identical if the initial publisher is from ROS 1 or ROS 2 side.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358103/ros-1-bridge-requires-the-topic-to-be-published-both-sides/) by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on ROS Answers with karma: 122 on 2020-07-27

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `dynamic_bridge` does **not** require a publisher on both sides. It requires a publisher on one side and a subscriber on the other.

The reason why `rostopic` / `ros2 topic`  `echo` isn't sufficient as a subscriber is described in the first section of the README: https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/blob/master/README.md#bridge-communication-between-ros-1-and-ros-2

The dynamic bridge only bridges topic which are necessary to bridge for efficiency reasons. So it doesn't bridge the published topic until a subscriber is present. `echo` on the other hand tries to determine the type of the specified topic automatically when invoked without a type. Since the topic doesn't exist yet that fails with the error message:

> Could not determine the type for the passed topic

You have multiple options to resolve this:

- You pass the topic type explicitly: e.g. `ros2 topic echo /test std_msgs/msg/Bool`
- You use the `--bridge-all-1to2-topics` option of the dynamic bridge (if the performance impact is acceptable)
- You use a different bridge (e.g. the `parameter_bridge`) to configure the bridged topics explicitly

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2020-07-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [screen33](https://answers.ros.org/users/40664/screen33/) on 2020-07-27**:
This is explained in the README but I hadn't really gotten it. Thank you!